doPost Triggered by Slack Not Calling Function from Different File in Same Project
I'm facing an issue with my Google Apps Script project and could use some help.
Short Summary: I have a project with three .gs files. One of them contains a doPost function that is triggered by Slack. To make this work, I published the project as both a Web App and an API Executable.
Problem: When the doPost function is triggered, it tries to call a function from another file within the same project, but the function doesn't seem to execute. However, if I create a file with only a function that calls the function from the other file, it works as expected.
I suspect the issue might be related to the fact that I'm calling the function from within the doPost context.
Here's my code:
function doPost(e) {
  var params = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  // Check if it is a URL verification request
  if (params.type === "url_verification") {
    // Extract the challenge value
    var challenge = params.challenge;
    
    // Return the challenge value as plain text
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(challenge).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }

  // Process message events
  if (params.event && params.event.text && params.event.text.toLowerCase() === "fila") {
    logMessage("Message 'fila' received and processed.");
    updateSheetWithMessage("fila");

    // Call the checkCandidates function only if the message is 'fila'
    checkCandidates();
  } else {
    logMessage("Message received: " + params.event.text);
  }

  // Return a response quickly to avoid Slack re-sending the message
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function updateSheetWithMessage(message) {
  var sheetId = '1Vpi30e6IUfMYNr06VXnw-zit-P6Lz7hLny2nJW86_JY';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName('Logs');
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(message);
}

function logMessage(message) {
  Logger.log(message);
}

What I've Tried:
I've tried creating a file with only a function that calls the function from the other file, and it worked.
I've checked that the functions are properly defined and can be called in isolation.
I've also tried setting a time based trigger to run the function later so it can respond to Slack under 3 seconds (I've read about a time limit in doPost in GAS) but it didn't work.
Suspected Cause: I believe the issue might be related to the doPost context in Google Apps Script.
Questions:
Is there a limitation or special consideration when calling functions from different files within the same project in a doPost context?
Are there any common pitfalls or best practices I should be aware of for this type of integration?
How can I ensure that checkCandidates is properly executed when triggered from Slack?

It's very likely that the problem is caused by the web app deployment settings combined with the spreadsheet sharing settings.
It might also be possible the deployed version doesn't include required changes.
You should Review the script execution logs as they might give You hints about the problem. Also You should review the web app deployment settings and the spreadsheet sharing settings.
